# PHP: What is the difference between password_hash and hash_hmac?

Tags: php

I have been reading the PHP documentation on password_hash and hash_hmac, but I am having trouble figuring out what the difference is between the two.

Are the purpose of both to create a hash, just using different algorithms? If so, do I just use one or the other, or do I use both?

```
$hash = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, $salt); 

$hash = password_hash($salt.$password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HMAC is a keyed hashing algorithm.  Given a secret key and a message, it generates a hash.  This is particularly useful for verifying message integrity: if you generate a token which includes a hash, you're then able to verify the the token was created with your secret key, and is thus trustworthy.  For instance, you might use this with a JWT implementation.

`password_hash` is built to automate creating salted password hashes.  Unlike keyed hashes, salted hashes include an appended plaintext, unique salt.  The purpose of the salt is to ensure that if the same password is hashed twice, it will have a different hash value due to the random salt applied to it.  This prevent attackers from using pre-computed hashes and from identifying duplicate passwords in your database.

So yes, they both create hashes, but they have different use cases.